# Jquery select value from drop down

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown that has a key value pair.

Through Jquery the followng didn't work

```
     $("#MainContent_degree").val('APN');
```

But the following did work:

```
   $("#MainContent_degree option:contains('APN')").attr('selected', true);
```

I thought they were one in the same.

Comment: The first one sets the option by checking the `option`'s `value` attribute. The second checks the actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with radio button, i think this will work with select fields:

**Removing the active selected option:**

```
$("#MainContent_degree").attr("selected", false);
```

**Setting the new selected option**

```
$("#MainContent_degree option[value='APN']").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your option element has a different `value` attribute and content. For `.val` to work you should set the `value` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/5abK4/2/.

```
<option value="APN">APN</option>
```

`:contains` searches for the content (i.e. the text between the tags).